# send html mail via yahoo mail api with JSON

Tags: html, yahoo-api

I am using to send [yahoo mail api](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/docs/user_guide/SendMessage.html) using JSON format to send mail. But even I use `\r\n` to make new line for the block of message that I want to send out, there is no effect when the recipient received it as a mail.

As there are some problem in making JSON if there are special characters, I am using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript` method to make my message string valid eg. hello friend.\r\n testing with special characters ~`!@#$%^&*() \n{}[]|?/.>,< .

[Sample JSON](https://github.com/ramiyer/YahooMailApiSample)

```
{
  "method": "SendMessage",
  "params": [
    {
      "savecopy": true,
      "message": {
        "to": {
          "email": "test@yahoo.com",
          "name": "SendMessage Test User"
        },
        "from": {
          "email": "ctest@yahoo.com",
          "name": "SendMessage Test User"
        },
        "replyto": {
          "email": "test@yahoo.com",
          "name": "SendMessage Test User"
        },
        "inreplyto": "SendMessage InReplyTo Value",
        "mailer": "YahooMailRC",
        "subject": "Message with Stationery",
        "simplebody": {
          "text": "hello friend.\r\n testing with special characters ~`!@#$%^&*() \n{}[]|?/.>,<",
          "html": "hello friend.\r\n testing with special characters ~`!@#$%^&*() \n{}[]|?/.>,<"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I use to escape `\` when I create a valid string to make JSON object.

Note: If I only set data in text , not in html. Nothing appeared in received mail.

How can I format the text that I want to send out via Yahoo mail api to retain all the new line (HTML format style) ?

Comment: how do I get "yahoo mail API " ? I noticed that your reference link is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding `<PRE>` tag to use the html format of my string.